# TypeError: core.defineInjectable is not a function while using angular material/cdk in angular 4.3.2

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cdk

I want to use angular material progress spinner and added

```
import {MatProgressSpinnerModule} from '@angular/material';
```

Added in imports array and in component

Haven't tried both updating the template with selector and removing it. In either case getting the error.

I am using system.config.js, and added map values for all the angular material and cdk js files.

Using angular 4.3.2 and angular material latest version. Getting this below error.

> errors.ts:42 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: TypeError:
>   core.defineInjectable is not a function
>         at eval (http://localhost:8000/node_modules/@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-bidi.umd.js:89:62)
>         at Object.eval (http://localhost:8000/node_modules/@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-bidi.umd.js:91:2)
>     Error loading
>   http://localhost:8000/app/UMSClient/com/ipc/ums/modules/EnterpriseTree/Enterprise.module.js
>         at eval (http://localhost:8000/node_modules/@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-bidi.umd.js:89:62)
>         at Object.eval (http://localhost:8000/node_modules/@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-bidi.umd.js:91:2)
>     Error loading
>   http://localhost:8000/app/UMSClient/com/ipc/ums/modules/EnterpriseTree/Enterprise.module.js

What could be wrong?

Thanks,

Comment: Can I ask why you're using SystemJS instead of WebPack with an Angular 4 project?

Comment: It is enterprise application already built with system js. We are planning to change to Webpack.

Answer (score 5):

`defineInjectable` is an angular 6 only function. You may have been using the newest version of Angular Material and it isn't compatible with your current version (4.3.2).

Answer (score 2):

I was getting this error on Stackblitz using Angular Material so I refreshed the dependancies and downgraded core-js to 2.6.9

`core-js @ 2.6.9`